# Jmeter Random function not generating question mark as string

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to create a test in Jmeter but when the data comes to my backend, the text displayed in debugger is "????"

My Json

[image]

And my debugger is showing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [__RandomString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) in a weird way.

As per [Functions Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) it takes 3 parameters:

1. Generated string length
2. Source characters to generate the string from
3. Name of [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) where to store the result

[image]

If you don't provide the `Chars to use for random string generation` it will generate the string from absolutely random characters which might be in different locales, i.e. Chinese and your HTTP Request sampler is not properly set for sending these characters.

You can try amending your functions to restrict it to use only English characters:

```
${__RandomString(15,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzz,)}
```

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)